# Storing string with unknown character

Tags: java, regex, string, character

Lets say I have a word T**y**re. In some countries spelling is different - T**i**re

Is it possible to store a string in Java so for example something like **T y|i re**  and if I check, maybe with use of regexp, it would return `true` like

```
String compare = "Ty|ire";
String detail = "Tyre";
String detail2 = "Tire";
System.out.println(detail.equalsIgnoreCase(compare))  // prints "true"
System.out.println(detail2.equalsIgnoreCase(compare)) // also "true"
```

Comment: If you grouped your letters the `|` would have operated as you expected.  `T(y|i)re`. Without the grouping it is `Ty` or `ire`.

Comment: If you have a fixed set of those `String`s then consider making them an enum.  Then use `Locale` to map to a human friendly spelling of the enum value.

Comment: @AndrewS could you please explain more in detail?. I dont really get what you are talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) regex, `String compare = "T[yi]re";`. The `[yi]` construct matches either `y` or `i`. Add `(?i)` (an embedded [`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) option) to match in a case insensitive way:

```
String compare = "(?i)T[yi]re";
String detail = "Tyre";
String detail2 = "Tire";
System.out.println(detail.matches(compare));  // prints "true"
System.out.println(detail2.matches(compare)); // also "true"
```

See the [online Java demo](http://ideone.com/bOZVc5)

If you have to alternate multicharacter parts of a string, use *alternation groups*, `(y|ies)` or `(?:y|ies)`.

Comment: `String compare = "(?i)T[yi]re";` needs to be of type pattern and not string, doesn't it?

Comment: @Akaitenshi: No, since `String#matches` accepts a regex `String`.

Comment: dziękuję :) thanx, works as expected. I'll accept in 5 min when system lets me